# Different components, same GCP project

Tags: terraform, hcl

How would you organize Terraform code if you had multiple code repositories that make up the same product (e.g.: front-end, API, microservices)? For example: The front-end only needs to provision buckets, and Load Balancer back-ends and routes. The API needs a VM, Load Balancer backends and Load Balancer routes, and a database.

All production infrastructure would be within the same project on the Google Cloud Platform. How would you organize Terraform files across these git repositories of each component? Also, the components would share the same Load Balancer, so how can I make the that so changes in one repository doesn't affect the resource for other codebases that use it.

Answer (score 1):

HashiCorp (maintainers of Terraform) have [created content](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/repotting-overgrown-terraform-repositories) specifically for addressing this. I recommend reviewing it to get a better idea of some of the options.